# Is it ok to say, "Hope we could cooperate with you next time"?

Tags: word-meaning

Is it ok to say

> Hope we could cooperate **then**.

or

> Hope we could cooperate **with you next time**.

I'm writing an email.

Comment: What are you trying to say and what is the situation? On the surface, without context, this sounds a little passive-aggressive to me, as if to imply that there was previously some _lack_ of cooperation.

Comment: Also, it is highly informal, since you do not use a subject in the sentence - you start with a verb. Informal and business do not go well togther.

Comment: "I hope we can be of more help to you next time."

Answer (score 1):

**We** = if you are speaking on behalf of the company
**I** = if you are the person whom customers turn to

> **We** ***[hope to be of service](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hope%20to%20be%20of%20service%22&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRiJ3lms3iAhXFUlAKHXq-B7wQ_AUICSgA&biw=1316&bih=647&dpr=1.1)*** to you next time
>   **I/we**  [***look forward to collaborating with***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22look%20forward%20to%20collaborating%20with%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLqqjKms3iAhXPL1AKHSNMA20Q_AUIFigB&biw=1316&bih=647) you, next time we meet